# BIP-0016 p2sh keys and altcoins

Tags: altcoin, p2sh

It appears that bitcoin addresses using p2sh keys have a different prefix to that of normal bitcoin addresses. Do other altcoins such as litecoin, peercoin, dogecoin etc include this functionality?

Comment: Most likely, they are 1:1 clones most of the time of BTC.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Upon looking at the source of a number of altcoins I have found that p2sh keys are built into all the ones I checked.

For P2SH, the first address byte will be:

> bitcoin: '05'
>   litecoin: '05'
>   peercoin: '75'
>   dogecoin: '16'
>   beavercoin: '05'
>   freicoin: '05'
>   protoshares: '05'
>   megacoin: '05'
>   primecoin: '53'
>   auroracoin: '05'

The tricky bit about this is that you can't nessesarily tell what network a P2SH address belongs to like you can with normal addresses.

The reason I wanted to know is so I could collate the version numbers for my project:

http://github.com/ryanralph/altcoin-address